# What does each of the options in the 'Low Detail Models' graphical setting do?

Tags: pc, technical-issues, sonic-and-sega-all-stars-racing

What does the 'One, Two, Three and Four Player' options in the 'Low Detail Models' graphical setting do?

[image]

I assumed that 'Off' will turn off  'Low Detail Models' (enabling high detail models - please correct me if I'm wrong). However, I'm not sure what the 'One, Two, Three and Four Player' options do exactly. Does it have anything to do with the number of racers currently on the screen, or racing at the current track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "`[Number]` Player" refers to the level of split-screen mode you're in.

So if you set it to "One Player," you'll force lower quality models (and prebaked shadows it seems) in all game played. If you set it to "Two Player" and it'll only reduced the quality when you play multiplayer (2P and above), and so on.

It's a nice way to allow people to use better graphics in single player and lower the quailty in split-screen modes, so you can maintain a decent framerate.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you can set the game and tell it when to use the low detail models.  At zero you always use the high at 2 player you start using the low detail when two players are playing etc.  I am guessing this is implying split screen play.

Comment: Do you reckon it also has anything to do with the number of racers currently on the screen, or at the current track?